# I'm creating program where you enter multiple symptoms and get medicine printed, problem is that i cant take multiple symptom as an input

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, user-input

```py
diz_med = {
 "headache": "dan-p 500 sos",
 "migraine": "rizanet 0.5 sos",
 "constipation": "ducolax"}


symptoms = input("enter symptoms : ")


print(diz_med[symptoms])
```

Comment: Example: input :- headache , migraine , constipation and output :- dan-p 500 sos, rizanet 0.5 sos , ducolax

Comment: The code you are showing only contains a single input() statement. That asks for input ... once. Why do you expect that do give you multiple things? You should learn what LOOPS are, or you assume: the user enters a string "symptomA symptomB ..." so you end up with one lengthy string, assuming that the multiple symptoms are separated by spaces (and then you could SPLIT up that string into multiple ones)

Comment: do you know before hand how many inputs you need ?

Comment: And note: this community isn't a replacement for you doing your homework. You learn programming by PROGRAMMING yourself. By sitting down, reading books, looking at the material your teachers gave you. Also note: there is a lot of help information how to properly format your input here. There is also a preview function. You want others to spend their time to help you for free, so you please take the time to learn how to write a proper question.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind

Answer (score 1):

You could just take different symptoms separated by  a comma and then use

```
symptoms = symptoms.split(",")
```

to get a list of all of the symptoms. From there you can just print them all using a for loop, something like:

```
for symptom in symptoms:
    print(diz_med[symptom])
```